# Stencil Buffer in Opengl

Tags: opengl, stencil-buffer, video-card

Stencil test in OpenGL Red Book says:

> the stencil test takes place only if there is a stencil buffer.

How can I find out, if there is a stencil buffer in my OpenGL / graphics card implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

All modern graphics cards will have a stencil buffer, the Red Book is referring to whether or not the stencil test is currently enabled (using `glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)` and `glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)`).

Comment: This seems a little misleading, there's more to using stencil buffer than just enabling it. Most importantly you have to request it to be included when you create the window (instructions are OS/window library specific), or else you won't get one.